# Use function template argument as class template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to get familiar with templates in C++ by implementing something similar to C#'s Linq. In the end querying data should look something like this

```
SomeIteratorType begin = /* ... */;
SomeIteratorType end = /* ... */;
typedef iterator_traits<SomeIteratorType>::value_type Type;

linq<int> query = linq<Type>(begin, end)
                  .where([](Type value) -> bool { return /* ... */; })
                  .select([](Type value) -> int { return value.some_property; });

for (int value : query)
    cout << value << endl;
```

I started with

```
template<typename Type>
class linq : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, Type> {
public:
    typedef bool (WherePredicate)(Type value);

    // ...
    // Copy-constructor, operator=, operator++, ...
    // ...

    // ...
    // Linq functions, e.g.
    linq& where (WherePredicate& predicate) const; // returns some specialization of the linq-class (should probably not name this "where")
    // ...
};
```

But how to declare the constructor `linq(begin, end)` from the example? If `begin` and `end` are of type `IteratorType` I need the resulting `linq` object to be of type `linq<std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type>`. Is it even possible to work out the class template argument from a function template argument? If not, is it at least possible to ensure that `IteratorType begin` and `IteratorType end` suffice `std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type == Type`, when used like `linq<Type>(begin, end)`?

Comment: You need to return a new type for every query statement, wrapping the previous query into the new type. stl style iterator won't help much.

Comment: I know, the functions `where`, `select`, `map`, etc. will return specializations of linq as to support further calls to linq functionality (for example, `where` will return a `linq_where` object initialized like `linq_where(*this, predicate)`. But my question is, how to declare the constructor `linq(begin, end)`. The problem is that I don't know how to compute the class template argument `Type` from the constructor's `IteratorType`.

Comment: Why won't STL style iterators help much? I mean all I'm really doing is reimplementing STL functions, to enable linq-like syntax.

Answer (score 0):

So C# uses heap allocated objects and indirection through interfaces as if it was free.

If you want to emulate that, you have to do the same.  If you also want value semantics you'll have to write wrappers that hold smart pointers and behave like values.

A different approach would be not to type erase; instead the linq object is a unique type for each chain of modifiers.  Here `linq` is a function not a tyoe, and you store return values in `auto` variables.

These two approaches can work together, like lambda (no type ersaure callables) and std function (value type that may heap allocate and type erases at construction to forget all but call interface of callable).

To get further, learn about type erasure (including how to write std function), regular types in C++, and maybe look into Rangesv3 a library that enables linq-like streaming expressions.